# Наша країна повільніше багатьох?

Tags: словотворення, морфологія

Є [посильніше](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&hs=3kz&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&gs_l=serp.3...9872.10673.0.11052.6.6.0.0.0.0.152.420.0j3.3.0....0...1.1.64.serp..3.0.0.2uS_54egSQw), є [подовше](http://sum.in.ua/s/podovshe); а чому повільніше має зовсім інше значення? І як тоді підсилити фразу "наша країна вільніше багатьох"?

Answer (score 13):

#### «Повільний» («поволі»)

Слова «[повільний](http://sum.in.ua/s/poviljnyj)», «[поволі](http://sum.in.ua/s/povoli)» вже усталилися в іншому значенні. За [«Етимологічним словником української мови» в 7 томах](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) слово вони дійсно походять від «вільний»/«воля», я уявляю принцип формування сучасних значень якось так: «повільно»/«поволі» — це коли людина щось робить невимушено, не під тиском термінових обставин чи наглядачів, відповідно в темпі, в якому сама [воліє](http://sum.in.ua/s/volity) (що теоретично не обов'язково означає кволий темп, іноді навпаки: людина, на яку нічого не тисне, робить з більшим ентузіазмом і відповідно швидше — але на практиці усталилося саме таке значення).

Причому прикметник «повільний» є [якісним](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/adjectif/adjecvyd.htm#vyd_1) (має степені порівняння). Тому «повільніший» строго асоціюється з «більш повільний» (а не чимось типу «побільш вільний»). В той час як «посильний» має [два значення](http://sum.in.ua/s/posyljnyj) («той, для якого вистачає сили» та «пов'язаний із посилками»), для обох з яких не дуже вживаними є ступені порівняння, тому   «посильніший»/«посильніше» в залежності від контексту і наголосу може асоціюватися і з «більш посильним» («поси́льніший для мене»=«той, що мені більш по силі»), і з «якнайсильніше» («вдар його посильні́ше») — принаймні в суржиковому мовленні.

#### Ступінь порівняння «по-» + основа + «-(і)ший»/«-(і)ше» і суржик

Таке формування слів в українській мові можливе лише для прислівників. (І насправді я не впевнений, що воно є чимось іншим за русизм навіть для прислівників. Хоча такі конструкції є в російській мові і, можливо, були в давньоруській, але в сучасній літературній українській, мені здається, звичайнішими є найвищий ступінь з «якнай-» (там, де він доречний) та простий вищий (в інших випадках): рос. «он приказал решить эту задачу побыстрее» → «він наказав виконати це завдання (розв'язати цю задачу) якнайшвидше», рос. «говорите потише, пожалуйста» → «розмовляйте тихіше, будь ласка». Окремі прислівники такого типу («[побільше](http://sum.in.ua/s/pobiljshe)», «[подовше](http://sum.in.ua/s/podovshe)», «[поменше](http://sum.in.ua/s/pomenshe)») потрапили в радянські словники — але це можуть бути просто винятки. Але я не маю інформації про притаманність прислівників виду «по-» + основа + «-(і)ше» різним діалектам української мови, тому не буду нічого стверждувати.)

В будь-якому разі, наскільки я можу бачити, ми не маємо прикметників «побільший», «подовший», «поменший» — лише прислівники «побільше», «подовше», «поменше». Але прислівники не можна застосовувати в такій ролі (незалежно від того, з «по-» чи без «по-» і який ступінь порівняння): ми кажемо «я сильніший/сильніша за тебе» (рос. «я сильнее тебя») — а не «я сильніше за тебе» (хіба що якщо мовець є явищем середньої статі, а не людиною: «я — відвічне зло — сильніше за тебе, лицарю»); тому й «наша країна вільніша від багатьох» — а не «наша країна вільніше від багатьох».

Можна зробити, щоб потрібен був саме прислівник (а не прикметник), використавши дієслово, наприклад, «наша країна живе вільніше від багатьох». В такому разі питання використання прислівника «по-» + основа + «-(і)ше» в цьому випадку залишається актуальним — але особисто для мене й питання про літературність таких прислівників (за винятком окремих випадків) залишається відкритим. В суржиковому мовленні, може, вийде сказати щось на зразок «наша країна живе по-вільн**і́**ше від багатьох», акцентувавши нетиповий прислівник нетиповим наголосом.

#### Пряма відповідь

«По*xxx*(і)ше» вживається (залежно від контексту) у двох різних значеннях:

1. Найчастіше (особливо, коли вказано або очевидно, з ким/чим порівнюємо): «суттєво (істотно, в значній мірі) *xxx*(і)ше». Наприклад, «говоріть потихіше» → «я прошу вас говорити значно тихіше».

   - <sub>Іноді: префікс не має ніякого сенсу, просто «*xxx*(і)ше». Фактично мовець вставляє «по-» не через значну різницю між потрібною мірою й еталонною мірою, а задля більшого впливу на слухачів (тоді «говоріть потихіше» означає не «говоріть *набагато* тихіше», а «мені *дуже* треба, щоб ви говорили тихіше»). Але й інші додаткові слова типу «суттєво», «істотно», «значно» люди теж в такому випадку можуть вставляти (це вже питання людської психології: коли людині дуже треба α, вона часто каже, що їй треба 10 α — хоч насправді їх треба всього α, але дуже треба).</sub>
2. Іноді: «якомога *xxx*(і)ше», «якнай*xxx*(і)ше». Наприклад, «зробіть побистріше» → «зробіть якомога швидше».

У даному випадку це перше значення. Тому: «наша країна значно (істотно, суттєво) вільніш**а** від багатьох».